# How to create a function that takes in a list as input and returns a 1 for each value that is above 0.5 and a 0 if below 0.5?

Tags: python, function, boolean-operations

I have a float list that I want to convert to a list containing 1 or 0 for each individual value depending on if they are greater than a certain value.

Example:

```
list=[0.4,0.6,0.7,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.8]

value=0.5
```

for each item in the list I want to change values greater than 0.5 to a 1 and values less than that to a 0.

I have tried this but keep getting a NoneType object which I won't be able to use in calculations later on.

```
    def fun1(list,value):
            for i in list:
                    if i > value
                            print(int(1))
                    if i < value
                            print(int(0))
```

I get the right numbers in the list [0,1,1,0,0,1,1]; however, it says the type is None. I want them to be integer values in the list so I can use them for computations later. What could I be doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: What about 0.5?  You can try something like `[1 if i >= 0.5 else 0 for i in mylist]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to threshold values in python without if statement (to zero if below threshold, same if above)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49044607/how-to-threshold-values-in-python-without-if-statement-to-zero-if-below-thresho)

Comment: The reason your getting `NoneType` is because you don't have a return statement.. your just printing values.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very easily using [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/).  I'd strongly recommend reading up and getting comfortable with this Pythonic convention.

For example:

```
output = [1 if i >= 0.5 else 0 for i in mylist]
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```py
my_list = [0.2, 23.2, 0.5, 0.4, 1.2, 1, .23,]

def my_function(in_list):
    out_list = []

    for number in in_list:
        if number <= 0.5:
            out_list.append(0)
            continue
        out_list.append(1)
    
    return out_list

print(my_function(my_list)) # returns [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Code breakdown:

```
    out_list = []
```

We need to initialize out_list as an array so that we can later use `append()` on it.

```
        if number <= 0.5:
            out_list.append(0)
            continue
```

This takes any value lower than or equal to zero, and adds it to the list. We then use `continue` so it goes back to the start of the `for` loop.
*Note: this could also be done without a `continue` and instead an `else` or `elif`, this was just my chosen method for this answer.*

```
        out_list.append(1)
```

This gets called only when a number is greater than 0.5. It adds 1 to `out_list`

Answer (score 0):

```
def greater_than(values, target):
    result = []
    for value in values:
        result.append(int(value > target))
    return result

values = [0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.3, 0.2, 0.7, 0.8]
result = greater_than(values, 0.5)
```

Alternatively, as a list comprehension:

```
values = [0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.3, 0.2, 0.7, 0.8]
result = [int(value > 0.5) for value in values]
```